# List of ImageJ color names

Tags: colors, imagej

In ImageJ ROI manager one can define a color by name (green, yellow, magneta, etc). I have been struggling to find a list of allowed color names. Does anybody know where to find a comprehensive list of color names used by ImageJ?

Comment: Surprisingly, @admdrew seems to be wrong: ImageJ uses its own subset of Java colors (see answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [ROI manager documentation](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub%3aROI-Manager...) of the ImageJ User Guide, it is written:

> The nine default selection colors (*black, blue, cyan, green, magenta, orange, red, white, yellow*) can be typed textually.

The same can be found in the source code: the [`RoiProperties`](http://fiji.sc/RoiProperties.java#l182) dialog uses the [`ij.plugin.Colors`](http://fiji.sc/Colors.java) class to set the stroke color.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I remember reading this from somewhere before, but asked because I forgot where to find the information. Then I always tried to google and did not find it again. I hope that now or after this question gets indexed it is possible to find the information with google.

Comment: @Jan Eglinger is it possible to do a dark gray?